# Create a multiple selection listbox custom activity in window workflow foundation

Tags: c#, wpf, workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-activity

I have created a custom activity in window workflow. In that activity there is a multiple selection listbox. When I select multiple value and save that workflow and next time I open that workflow from file only one item is selected in it. It is not showing multiple items.

### activity code is below

```
[Designer(typeof(StatusQueueDesigner))]    
public sealed class StatusQueueCodeActivity : CodeActivity
{      
    [Description("Enter Queue Name")]
    [RequiredArgument]
    public InArgument<string> Queue { get; set; }
    public string showInList { get; set; }
    public string showInDropdown { get; set; }
```

}

in above code showInDropdown variable is bind with listbox

### listbox XAML Code is below

```
 <ListBox 
        Grid.Column="1" 
        x:Name="listbox"
        SelectedValue="{Binding Path=ModelItem.showInDropdown, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ModelToObjectValueConverter} }"
        SelectionMode="Multiple"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Height="100"
        Margin="12,10,0,0" 
        Grid.Row="4" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="278" 
        SelectionChanged="listbox_SelectionChanged"
        />
```

### and the code for workflow saved is following

```
 <FlowStep x:Name="__ReferenceID0">
<sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
  <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
    <av:Point x:Key="ShapeLocation">86,122</av:Point>
    <av:Size x:Key="ShapeSize">448,356</av:Size>
  </scg:Dictionary>
</sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
<aa:StatusQueueCodeActivity DisplayName="Queue 1" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="448,356" Queue="[&quot;Queue&quot;]" showInDropdown="2" showInList="4">
  <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
    <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
      <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
    </scg:Dictionary>
  </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
</aa:StatusQueueCodeActivity>
```

If you need any other information then please let me know. I am stuck in this problem from more than a week. please provide a solution.
Thanks in advance
regards

Comment: Please refer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728356/add-multiple-property-metadata-to-a-dependency-property-in-a-workflow-activity?rq=1